# Visual Studio testing interface crashing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, testing, xunit

When I try to run some unit tests in Visual Studio, the Test Explorer starts the test then I get the following error indicator in Test Explorer:

[image]

The test keeps in blue, it doesn't pass and neither fails, as if it was not run.

And in my Output window I get the following error:

```
Building Test Projects
========== Starting test run ==========
The active test run was aborted. Reason: Test host process crashed : Process is terminated due 
to StackOverflowException.
Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException.
Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException.

========== Test run aborted: 0 Tests (0 Passed, 0 Failed, 0 Skipped) run in < 1 ms ==========
```

But I cannot see any indication of stack overflow in the test. No huge call stacks or memory spikes, which is usually an indicator of that.

I get to this piece of code, by debugging line by line:

```
public async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken ct)
{
   Logger.Information("Stopping consumers and workers...");

   try
   {
       try
       {
          _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           Logger.Error(ex, "Exception during cancellation of the AJQ consumers / workers");
       }

      var timeout = _config.Bootstrapper.StopServiceTimeout;
      Logger.Information($"Stop of worker/consumer tasks requested (waiting for: {timeout.TotalSeconds} sec for tasks to complete)");
      var delayTask = Task.Delay(timeout, ct);
      var waitAllTask = Task.WhenAll(AllTasks);
      var tasks = new[] { delayTask, waitAllTask };
      await Task.WhenAny(tasks).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      Logger.Error(ex, "Exception ... ");
    }
}
```

In the last line when I press F10, the test simply stops, no error, no exception, nothing, it just stops running.

Any insight on how I could get more information about why this is happening?

Comment: What is `AllTasks`?

Comment: This is (at least partially) a debugger issue. A `StackOverflowException` is not handled nicely by the debugger and/or the runtime causing the behavior you observe (process exits without a trace). You need to step into the code until you can see where the error happens.

Comment: @mu88 I don't think this matters, because if I change the line `var tasks = new[] { delayTask, waitAllTask };` to `var tasks = new[] { delayTask };` I get the same weird behavior.

Comment: @PMF That was my 1st try, but in the code there is no `StackOverflowException` being thrown at all, that's what is making it very weird for me.

Comment: Do you have some repro code for us? Because I tried to reproduce it, but without luck

Comment: @rbasniak Of course you're not throwing StackOverflowException anywhere yourself. This one is (in case you really have a stack overflow) thrown deep inside the runtime. But (that's my experience at least) it may be that the stack is already so full that the runtime is unable to properly handle this situation and just dies. You might see some additional information in the Windows event log.

Comment: @PMF I meant the exception is not being thrown during runtime, I didn't mean I searched for it being thrown manually sorry for the confusion.

Comment: For those coming by in the future. I found the issue. There was a log method calling itself by mistake. But this happened so fast in the code that I couldn't catch it. What I did was insert several `Debug.WriteLine` statements in several methods. This allowed me to see this happening.

Comment: Can you provide more code for me to reproduce? The error is "Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException.". Probably the reason for citing itself.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error and it was because of my code. It was because, I created an object for the class in the same class(copy paste mistake, copied object from another class), removing the object and its references solved the issue for me.

Ex: In the "Car" class, I created "Car" object and referencing methods by Car.method by removing "car" object and calling methods directly resolved the issue.